# Charts.js & Bootstrap Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, charts, chart.js

I have been trying to understand why [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction) wouldn't draw a chart if it's inside a [Bootstrap Accordion](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#accordion).

After many attempts I managed to understand why it's not drawing the chart! it's because the panel is basically *hiding* the canvas so Charts.js doesn't draw it.

Can anyone help me come up with a solution to this?

I've also tried to draw the chart only when the Bootstrap event `shown.bs.collapse` is active, doesn't work.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ken6wq5w/2/) I've created to illustrate the problem:

If you want to reproduce the problem simply add `in` to the class in line `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with the following code:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <canvas id="q_chart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("q_chart").getContext("2d");
var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
    }, {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
    }]
};
var MyNewChart=null;
$('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
      if(MyNewChart == null)
          MyNewChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data);
  },200);
});
```

Comment: Right, it works, now... do you mind explaining why your code works? :)

Comment: @odedta as you say chartjs doesn't work beacuse the panel is basically hiding the canvas, so we need to run chartjs when the panel shown, but event  'shown.bs.collapse' fired when the panel is steal hide (just a few milisecond before panel show completely) so i just create a delay to make sure that the panel show completely

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing and found that you can call `MyNewChart.update()` instead of recreating the chart on a timeout as the verified answer does. The first transition is a bit rough (maybe because a transition is happening as it's created) but after that the transitions are smooth.

Example JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/akh9cnx5/

```
<div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="col-12 btn btn-light mb-2" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#viewgraph" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="viewgraph">View Graph</button>
    <div id="viewgraph" class="collapse mb-2">
        <div class="card card-body">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                    <canvas id="graph"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');

var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }, {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }]
};

var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data
});

$("#viewgraph").on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
  myNewChart.update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this later, I had the same issue but preferred not to rely on a timer delay as offered in the accepted answer. The following is what worked for me using Bootstrap 3.3.7 with the ***shown*** event:

> **shown**.bs.collapse

```
$('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {

            switch (e.target.id)
            {
                case "panel1": ShowChart1(); break;
                case "panel2": ShowChart2(); break;
                case "panel3": ShowChart3(); break;
                case "panel4": ShowChart4(); break;
                default: ShowDefault();
            }

        })
```

Hopes this helps

btw - this is the above code working: [greatdata.com/stats/newyork_ny](http://greatdata.com/stats/newyork_ny)